# TextView HTML with anchor link

Tags: android, textview, fromhtml

I have a text in HTML with links external and internal (page navigation). When I use this text in Html.fromHtml and display it in a TextView, external links work, but inside the page itself, it does not go. I have already tried both setMovementMethod and Linkify - everything is not right. I know that it works through WebView, but it will be much faster and more convenient to work this way.

Code sample:

```
private void showText(String text) {
        TextView content = view.findViewById(R.id.textContent);
        content.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  
    }
```

Text sample:

```
The text is long, contained in a ScrollView, has <a name="sdfootnoteAanc" href="#sdfootnoteAsym"> links </a> within itself, such as footnotes. When pressed, the text should scroll to <a name="sdfootnoteAsym" href="#sdfootnoteAanc"> link location </a>, and then back - as often happens on sites.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your TextView in ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```